# Facebook Graph API - get a photos album ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an application that uploads a photo to facebook. I'm not supplying an album ID so an album is created on behalf of my app.

My question is: how do I get the album ID the photo was uploaded to?

When I `GET` the the photo information the album isn't present in the JSON which was my hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been bugging me for a while as well, but I think I have cracked the nut.

The album ID is hidden in the link value, so if you have a photo-post object from the Graph API, you can retrieve the Album ID like this:

```
NSString *link = [item valueForKey:@"link"];
NSString *album_id = nil;
NSRange fRange = [link rangeOfString:@"set=a."];
if(fRange.location != NSNotFound) {         
    NSInteger firstPos = fRange.location + 6;
    NSInteger endPos = [link rangeOfString:@"." options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(firstPos, 25)].location;
    album_id = [[link substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(firstPos, endPos - firstPos)] copy];
}
```

It could probably all be stripped down to one line of code, but I think this is more readable.
For getting the album information use:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:album_id andDelegate:delegate];
```

For getting all the photos in an album use:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", album_id] andDelegate:delegate];
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: This solution seems brittle, but I don't know of an alternative. It's really a shame that the photo itself doesn't have a connection to its album.

Comment: These days the album is a field that you can access from the photo object - i.e. ?fields=album - use the Graph API Explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer for more fields that you can add.

Comment: what is facebook here?

Answer (score 9):

**Jimmy Sawczuk**'s answer is close, but doesn't work because FQL Photo table columns `aid` and `pid` are Rest/FQL API ids, not Graph API ids.

Fortunately the `object_id` and `album_object_id` columns in this table are indexable ([contrary to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/210238719050049)) so this should give you both Rest/FQL & Graph ids for the album:

```
select aid, album_object_id from photo where object_id = ${GRAPH_PHOTO_ID}
```

In general `object_id` fields in Rest/FQL API responses are Graph API id (except for photo notifications, where it's the Rest/FQL id).

Re **HonkyHonk**'s answer: not all photo `link` urls have a `set` parameter; in this case I think you can find the Rest/FQL API photo id from its other parameters, and then use Rest/FQL API to get the album id:

- For users with 32-bit user-ids: calculate `(id << 32) | pid`

  - eg for http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=7518353&id=549683637 this gives `2360873244068853905`
- Otherwise concatenate `id`, `_` and `pid`

  - eg for http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=155052&id=100002937903251 this gives `100002937903251_155052`

It would help a lot if Facebook could document something about the two types of ids.  Also the Graph API Photo schema should include the album's Graph API id.

Comment: The `set` parameter of `link`, if present, contains the Graph API album id.

Comment: I've also seen some `link` urls where `set` is of the form `at.${ALBUMID}.${REST}`.  Wow, this is complex.

Answer (score 6):

This is the easy way to get it :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have the photo ID but need the album ID. You could try using [the `photo` FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) with the following query:

```sql
SELECT aid, pid FROM photo WHERE pid = '<your photo id>'
```

Comment: Are you uploading your photo to the user's "Wall Photos" album? If so, I'm not sure it belongs to any album that you can query; it's sort of bizarre. Additionally, do you have the `user_photos` permission?

Comment: No, the photo is uploaded to an album that is created by the app. Yes, the user_photos permission is set.

Answer (score 2):

Long, clunky, but theoretically valid way:
`http://graph.facebook.com/userid/albums`will get you a list of all the albums the user lets you see, then you can search the album objects ([api here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)) `for created_times` that match the time you created the album, which you can store when you create the album.

This is almost certainly a horrible way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly elegant but I'm not having much like finding a better solution ... I'll keep looking and if I keep coming up empty I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Barnett's solution works well for me, I use this as an FQL query through the Graph API to get a JSON response like I would for any other Graph API query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+album_object_id+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id='[PHOTOID]'
```

This returns:

```js
{
   "data": [
      {
         "album_object_id": "10150531092908837"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you can access the album ID using:

```php
<?php

$strPhotoAlbumID = $objFacebookAPI->data[0]->album_object_id;

?>
```

This is the cleanest solution i've found as Facebook constantly change the format of their photo and album URLs so parsing these with RegEx wont work as a long term fix.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using the legacy REST api since the album ID is passed with the link to the image in the server response. I then used a regex to pull the id out.

Not the best solution and I wouldn't recommend it but I feel its better than adding another several server requests to the code.

Comment: Can you give some details on exactly how you did this, and with what methods?  I'm looking at the response for the graph.facebook.com request for a photo id, and I'm not seeing anything in any of the URLs that's the album id from whence it came.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I had to pass up on Graph and just use REST

Answer (score 0):

```php
function get_album_id_by_album_name($album_name){//return array of data
    $fql = 'SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner=me() and name="'.$album_name.'"';
    $param = array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'callback'  => ''
    );
    $fqlResult = $this->facebook->api($param);
    return $fqlResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String albumID = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=192570127478130&set=a.135556629846147.24342.100001754323389&type=1";
albumID = albumID.split("&set=a.")[1];
albumID = albumID.split("\\.")[0];
System.out.println(albumID);
```